# Display generic query designer

Tags: sql-server-2008, bids

How do I display the generic query designer? I have instructions for an old version of SQL Server and they don't match up to SQL Server 2008 BIDS. The outside program where I will deploy the report has issues when using the graphic designer.

Answer (score 0):

goto Report Data Pane --> Rigth Click --> Dataset Properties --> Choose your Data Source --> and then you can see the below window with option for `Query Designer` or `Stored Procedure`

[image]

<kbd>[Read Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345246.aspx)</kbd> for more details